# Get called twice

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Have a FlowDocument that is a public property
It is bound in XAML
It is fairly expensive to create
Need to create it dynamically as any of a number of inputs may have changed
Also it is large - do not want to hold a copy 
Forget about if a copy or reference if actually held - it is expensive to create - a large loop with lots for formatting.
It is dynamic - it is created on each call to get

This public property is not referenced in code behind
In XAML it is only bound once

NotifyPropertyChanged is only called once
But I see two calls to get
The stack trace does not change at all so I suspect it is two call from XAML

I don't want to create the FlowDocument twice for one call to NotifyPropertyChanged
How can I fix this?

```
public FlowDocument DocFlow
{
    get
    {
        FlowDocument docFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        // expensive build docFlowDocument 
        return docFlowDocument;
    }
}
```

Holding a reference is not a solution

```
private FlowDocument docFlow;
```

This is dynamic content and any number of inputs could have changed.

One solution is to hold a copy of the prior inputs and prior output as page level private variable.
Then compare all the current inputs and if no input have changed then return the prior output.
Both the inputs and output can be large so I would rather not hold a copy.
HighCore I know a reference is not a copy.  But a single reference to prior input and prior output is memory.

I am not able to reproduce this in a very simple example.
The real app has frames and tabs.
I am working on a scaled down version of the app to reproduce the problem.
I will work on it some more but if I cannot reproduce the problem I will delete the question.

Comment: I believe one call is when it binds after `InitializeComponent()` and one is when you call the `INPC`.

Comment: `Also it is large - do not want to hold a copy` - You don't "hold a copy". As with any other .Net refence types, keeping a reference to the object in a variable or property does not "copy" the object.

Comment: @HighCore  How does that fix my problem?   I create docFlowDocument on demand and don't save ANY reference.

Comment: @Bob Not about InitializeComponent().  After the page is created a single call to NotifyPropertyChanged results in two calls to get.

Comment: Oh, after the Loaded is done. Where is `INPC` called? Any chance the location it is in, is called twice?

Comment: @Bob. As stated in my question and my prior comment.  "A single call to NotifyPropertyChanged results in two calls to get".

Comment: From where? Show the stack trace...

Comment: @bob I am done repeating for you what was already answered.  NotifyPropertyChanged is called once.  Two calls to get.  On the two calls to get there is no change to the stack trace.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's something inbetween both `get` statements or if you're calling the property inside the `get` statement, which you've been avoiding to answer. XAML doesn't magically call itself twice...

Comment: @bob Asked and answered.  For the third time there is nothing in the call stack between the two calls to get. If I called the property in the get that would result in a endless loop and a crash.

Comment: @Blam What do you mean there is no call stack between the two calls? It is literally empty? I doubt that.